# Currently my script's logic is **A or B then C**, but I want my script's logic to be **A or (B then C)

Tags: bash

Based on [Multiple logical operators, ((A || B) && C), and "syntax error near unexpected token"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290146/multiple-logical-operators-a-b-c-and-syntax-error-near-unexpected-t) I tried this...

```
sh -c [["wmctrl -a 'To Do List - Google Sheets' || (google-chrome --new-window https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oh7XWRTWoy5izkz4eV6G7vZKgdwNeZa_NW-VCdR5GUk/edit#gid=0 && xdotool key F11")]]
```

but it didn't work.

The URL below is associated with "To Do List - Google Sheets"

```
sh -c "wmctrl -a 'To Do List - Google Sheets' || "(google-chrome --new-window https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oh7XWRTWoy5izkz4eV6G7vRKgdwNeZa_NW-VCdR5GUk/edit#gid=0 && xdotool key F11)"
```

Because `google-chrome --start-fullscreen` does not work on my machine which is running Linux Mint 20.3, I appended `xdotool key F11` to cause Google Chrome to open full screen.

That works properly the first time I run the script, but subsequently `xdotool key F11` toggles full screen. I understand what is happening, but I don't know how to cause `xdotool key F11` to only run in case part B were to run (assuming my script were considered to be **A || B**) but not part A were to run.

In other words, currently my script's logic is **A or B then C**, but I want my script's logic to be **A or (B then C)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you save yourself some grief by writing it legibly

```bash
export url=https://...
sh -c '
    if ! wmctrl -a "To Do List - Google Sheets"; then 
        google-chrome --new-window "$url" && xdotool key F11
    fi
'
```

---

For a one-liner, just remove the newlines and add a semicolon before "fi"

```bash
sh -c 'if ! wmctrl -a "To Do List - Google Sheets"; then google-chrome --new-window '"$url"' && xdotool key F11; fi'
```

Or, using the boolean control operators, and braces to group the right-hand side of `||` (note the semicolon before the close brace is required)

```bash
sh -c 'wmctrl -a "To Do List - Google Sheets" || { google-chrome --new-window '"$url"' && xdotool key F11; }'
```

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help. I was planning on pasting into a keyboard shortcut in Linux Mint as one big long line. That's the one of the reasons I made it ugly. The other reason, is that I'm a Bash novice.

Comment: But I assume I can probably trigger a "pretty-looking Bash script" from a keyboard shortcut in Linux Mint. In such a case a pretty-looking Bash script would be a better solution.

Comment: @Ristelan consider putting your code in a function and then define the keyboard shortcut to reference the function; this allows you to maintain the code in (more) readable format while still using a single line in the keyboard shortcut definition; and yeah, you could do the same thing with a bash script

Comment: I ran your script. It seems like it works! I guess I'll launch it with a Python script (because I know how to launch Bash scripts from Python) and bind that Python script to a keyboard shortcut. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @Ristelan if you're prepared to use python, why not write the whole script in python?

Comment: Why not write the whole script in python? Because I don't know how. Like many novices, I cobble together kludgy solutions. I'm not proud of that; but that's what I do.

Comment: Or the other way around: if you are writing a bash script, why not bind the bash script to a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @glenn jackman I successfully ran the first one you created, "For a one-liner, just remove the newlines and add a semicolon before "fi". Thank you! Also, thanks much for pointing out the semicolon at the end of your boolean one liner. To me, Bash syntax is a bit cryptic at times.

Comment: Yes, it's a journey.

Comment: @ "if you are writing a bash script, why not bind the bash script to a keyboard shortcut?" Now I will bind the first one liner bash script to a keyboard shortcut which @glenn jackman created above. When feasible, experts create clean, terse solutions. I'm a novice who creates ugly, verbose solutions because of my limited knowledge.

Comment: "Yes, it's a journey." Sure. I agree. The logic used to solve problems today is the same as it was thousands of years ago, but the tools for writing code keep getting easier and easier to use. I expect within another 25 to 50 years, people will be able to use something similar to human language to create code because artificial intelligence will act in a manner akin to a translator. Don't get me wrong: the human language will need to be precise. I imagine saying, "HAL, currently my script's logic is A or B then C, but I want my script's logic to be A or (B then C), please translate that."

Comment: @glenn jackman I checked https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman. I'd like to "buy you a coffee" but I prefer to use Bitcoin instead of my Mastercard. Do you accept Bitcoin?

Comment: I don't. It truly is the thought that counts. Your appreciation is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

- '[[' ']]' is for bash, not sh. So, `sh -c "[["` would not work anyway
- You need a space after '[[' and before ']]'
- '[[' ']]' are logic operator. Not something to start commands in it. So, I don't think you should be using them at all any way. `[[ "firefox" ]]` doesn't start firefox at all, and has nothing to do with firefox command. It is just true (meaning that `[[` built in returns a 0 exit code) because "firefox" string is not empty. As would be `[[ "wqyupfwirarav" ]]` or anything. ```

So, from what you said, I surmise that what you are looking for is

```bash
wmctrl -a 'To Do List - Google Sheets' || ( google-chrome --new-window "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oh7XWRTWoy5izkz4eV6G7vZKgdwNeZa_NW-VCdR5GUk/edit#gid=0"   && xdotool key F11" )
```

Or, even better, since there is no need for subshell (`( ... )` starts a new shell in which it executes ... ; so `( bla || foo )` is a little bit like `bash -c "bla || foo"` )

```bash
wmctrl -a 'To Do List - Google Sheets' || { google-chrome --new-window "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oh7XWRTWoy5izkz4eV6G7vZKgdwNeZa_NW-VCdR5GUk/edit#gid=0"  && xdotool key F11 ; }
```

Note the compulsory `;` at the end of the compound grouping (`{ ... }`).
This doesn't start a subshell. It just executes `wmctrl ...` command and, if it fails, executes `google-chrome` command and then the xdotool command.

Note that I also enclosed the google-chrome url in double quote. At first glance it is not necessary here (not even sure tho), but generally speaking url could contain some `&` or things like that, that could require quoting in order not to be interpreted by bash.

Comment: "So, sh -c "[[" would not work anyway", and "You need a space after '[[' and before ']]'", and "'[[' ']]' are logic operator." I see. Thanks. "Note the compulsory ;" It looks weird to me, but I noted it.  I was unable to get your first solution to work, but your second solution—the one without a subshell— worked perfectly both with the double quotation marks around the URL and without the double quotation marks around the URL. Thank you!!